# Want to show all freeform entries

Tags: solspace-freeform

Freeform documentation says exp:freeform:entries limit defaults to 20. I want to show all entries.

When I add limit="200" - even though right now there aren't 200 entires - the page takes forever to load. At least 3x as long. Problem is that client is hoping for 2000+ entries eventually.

Suggestions? Solspace, ideas?

Thanks
Amanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exp:freeform:entries in Low Vars. I don't remember if preparsing was turned on or not. Anyway once I moved the code to an embedded template all was smooth.

Sorry for not thinking through and trying stuff on my own before asking here.